# Append rows to a Spreadsheet without loading whole file

Tags: java, file-io, spreadsheet, xls, outputstream

I have been using the apache POI library to create XLS files but find it limited both in the fact that is follows the [Microsoft Excel spec](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=1) and also in the way that it requires you to have your entire Workbook loaded in memory if you want to append to it.

Are there any other libraries or techniques (save hand coding the XLS XML itself) that allow you to stream the contents of an XLS document, row by row, with out needing more then the full workbook loaded in memory?

Comment: Are you locked into XLS as the storage format? Because storing as CSV then converting to XLS on demand would give you a significant amount of flexibility in managing the data.

Comment: @Perception Yes unfortunately I am locked into XLS. I do use TSV (tab separated value) files but have met a scenario where I need to dump large XLS files.

Comment: Unfortunately, the alternatives to manipulating XLS files in Java is rather limited. You might have to manually append to the data in question

Comment: How large a file are you dealing with?  Unless it's multiple gigabytes you probably shouldn't be worrying about loading it into memory.

Comment: Well I am currently running out of memory when I have 10/15 on the go at one time (required). Each is c.500k rows... I've got 2048MB of java heap to work with.